# C# mapping php params

Tags: c#, php, browser, parameters

I have a string that contains ?action=a&current=b&something=c
i want to create a variable that i can do val = mymap['current']; Is there something in C# to parse this? or do i need to use a string.split and write my own func?

-edit-
solved thanks to REA_ANDREW and Guy Starbuck (from the other thread).

```
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
//add System.Web reference to project
NameValueCollection q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(link.Substring(link.IndexOf("?")+1));
//value = q["key"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question shows a really fit for purpose method:

[How to parse a query string into a NameValueCollection in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624/how-to-parse-a-query-string-into-a-namevaluecollection-in-net)

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
```

Andrew