# Best way to convert query string to dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

I'm looking for the simplest way of converting a query string from an HTTP GET request into a Dictionary, and back again.

I figure it's easier to carry out various manipulations on the query once it is in dictionary form, but I seem to have a lot of code just to do the conversion. Any recommended ways?

Answer (score 74):

`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` parses query string into a `NameValueCollection` object, converting the latter to an `IDictionary<string, string>` is a matter of a simple `foreach`. This, however, might be unnecessary since `NameValueCollection` has an indexer, so it behaves pretty much like a dictionary.

Comment: and back again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c

Comment: Request.QueryString is Already a NameValueCollection, @H70 answer is the easiest for putting into a dictionary `var parameters = Request.QueryString.Keys.Cast<string>().ToDictionary(k => k, v => Request.QueryString[v]);`

Comment: I've just tried to use it, and I think it has a problem: the resultant `NameValueCollection` values are silently modified when iterated. For example, try calling `var q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("firstParam=cGFzc35+d29yZA==")` (this is the base64 encoding for the string `pass~~word`), and then iterate it using `for (var i = 0; i <= q.Keys.Count; ++i) { var val = q[q.Keys[i]]; }`. Watch `val`'s value: You'll get `cGFzc35 d29yZA==` instead of `cGFzc35+d29yZA==`.

Comment: @OfirD - There's an overload which takes in encoding - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=net-7.0#system-web-httputility-parsequerystring(system-string-system-text-encoding)

Answer (score 45):

Here is how I usually do it

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Keys.Cast<string>()
    .ToDictionary(k => k, v => HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[v]);
```

Comment: Easy and straightforward! Deserves a +1  :-)

Comment: for elegant answer

Comment: Note that they key can be null, which will cause the statement to fail.  I fixed it by changing ".ToDictionary(k => k,..." to ".ToDictionary(k => k ?? "", ...".  (You can use any default value for "k" that you want.)

Answer (score 22):

How about [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)?

Just add a reference to System.Web.dll

Answer (score 20):

Same as Sean, but with Linq (and a function you can copy and paste):

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ParseQueryString(string queryString)
{
   var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
   return nvc.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => nvc[k]);
}
```

Also, the question asked how to get it back into a query string:

```
public static string CreateQueryString(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
   return string.Join("&", parameters.Select(kvp => 
      string.Format("{0}={1}", kvp.Key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value))));
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just had to do this for a mono compatible solution

```
Regex.Matches(queryString, "([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?").Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[1].Value, x => x.Groups[3].Value)
```

Comment: Works for Windows Phone 8 too (the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` doesn't exist there too).

Comment: @BinaryWorrier and if they're not a simple .GroupBy(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().Groups[3].Value); would work (with obvious data loss)

Comment: This answer is perfect for me, since I'm programming C# within Unity. Kinda surprised a solution for that environment was so hard to find, but oh well.

Comment: btw this code relies on 'System.Linq' and 'System.Text.RegularExpressions;'

Answer (score 10):

In ASP.NET Core, use [ParseQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers.parsequery).

```
var query = HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value;
var queryDictionary = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 7):

I like the brevity of [Jon Canning's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15419842/522150), but in the interest of variety, here is another alternative to his answer, that would also work for restricted environments like Windows Phone 8, that lack the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` utility:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ParseQueryString(String query)
    {
        Dictionary<String, String> queryDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (String token in query.TrimStart(new char[] { '?' }).Split(new char[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            string[] parts = token.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (parts.Length == 2)
                queryDict[parts[0].Trim()] = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parts[1]).Trim();
            else
                queryDict[parts[0].Trim()] = "";
        }
        return queryDict;
    }
```

Actually, a useful improvement to Canning's answer that take care of decoding url-encoded values (like in the above solution) is:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ParseQueryString2(String query)
    {
       return Regex.Matches(query, "([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?").Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[1].Value, x => HttpUtility.UrlDecode( x.Groups[3].Value ));
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

One liner without HttpUtility

```cs
var dictionary = query.Replace("?", "").Split('&').ToDictionary(x => x.Split('=')[0], x => x.Split('=')[1]);
```

Comment: ok, I haven't thought of that use case. 
You could add `.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))` before the `.ToDictionary` to avoid that exception

Comment: You can simply add a StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries parameter to .Split('&'):

.Split(new [] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way to do it:

```
NameValueCollection nvcData = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
Dictionary<string, string> dictData = new Dictionary<string, string>(nvcData.Count);
foreach (string key in nvcData.AllKeys)
{
    dictData.Add(key, nvcData.Get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just get it by decorating the parameter with the `FromQueryAttribute`

```
public void Action([FromQuery] Dictionary<string, string> queries)
{
    ...
}
```

P.S. If you want to get multiple values for each key you can change the Dictionary to `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Answer (score 1):

Most simple:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.QueryString.Count; i++)
{
    parameters.Add(context.Request.QueryString.GetKey(i), context.Request.QueryString[i]);
}
```

Comment: Add a description to your code segment, Just the code block wont help much.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *converting* `HttpContext.Request.QueryString` to `Dictionary<>`, try using

```
HttpContext.Request.Query
```

which already is a `Dictionary<string, StringValues>`

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this post whilst looking for the same solution for an Azure WebJob, hopefully this helps others doing the same.

If you are coding an Azure WebJob you use the `GetQueryParameterDictionary()` extension method.

```
var queryParameterDictionary = request.GetQueryParameterDictionary();
```

where *request* is of type `HttpRequest` and *queryParameterDictionary*  is now of type `IDictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 1):

AspNet Core now automatically includes `HttpRequest.Query` which can be used similar to a dictionary with key accessors like this:

```cs
var x = Current.Request.Query["x"];
```

However if you needed to cast it for logging or other purposes, you can pull out that logic into an extension method like this:

```cs
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
  public static Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this IQueryCollection query)
  {
    return query.Keys.ToDictionary(k => k, v => (string)query[v]);
  }
}
```

Then, you can consume it on your httpRequest like this:

```cs
var queryParams = Current.Request.Query.ToDictionary()
```

---

**Further Reading**

- [How to parse a query string into a NameValueCollection in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68624/1366033)
- [Convert query string to key-value pair in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9669839/1366033)
- [Is it possible to get Dictionary from query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22707788/1366033)