# Convert a delimted string to a dictionary<string,string> in C#

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, delimiter

I have a string of the format
"key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;"

I need to convert it to a dictionary for the above mentioned key value pairs.

What would be the best way to go about this?
Thanks.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776107/best-way-to-convert-query-string-to-dictionary-in-c  I suppose you'd have to replace your `;` with `&` before that would work though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a delimited string to a dictionary<string,uint> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091071/convert-a-delimited-string-to-a-dictionarystring-uint-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 111):

Something like this?

```
var dict = text.Split(new[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(part => part.Split('='))
               .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);
```

Of course, this will fail if the assumptions aren't met. For example, an `IndexOutOfRangeException` could be thrown if the text isn't in the right format and an `ArgumentException` will be thrown if there are duplicate keys. Each of these scenarios will require different modifications. If redundant white-space could be present, you may need some `string.Trim` calls as necessary.

Comment: This might be obvious to some, but you need to include `System.Linq` for the `Select()`.

Answer (score 29):

Updated Ani's to take in account the semi colon at the end. The where clause will ensure that you have a key and value before creating and entry.

```
var dictionary = "key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;"
    .Split(';')
    .Select (part  => part.Split('='))
    .Where (part => part.Length == 2)
    .ToDictionary (sp => sp[0], sp => sp[1]);
```

Answer (score 20):

You could do this using JSON string, for example:

```
var dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, string>>("{'1':'One','2':'Two','3':'Three'}");
```

Comment: [Best solution]. I prefer have the values in json format than just random text . Thank you

Answer (score 12):

Behold the awesome whitespace ignoring, correcting for last value having or not having a semicolon power of regular expressions:

```
        var dict = Regex.Matches("key1 = value1; key2 = value2 ; key3 = value3", @"\s*(.*?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*(;|$)")
        .OfType<Match>()
        .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
```

But seriously though, Ani deserves props for the .ToDictionary().  I would never have thought of that.

Answer (score 10):

You could write it like this or loop over it to do it yourself. Either way. Ultimately, you're splitting on `;` to get the item pairs, then on `=` to get the key and value.

```
string input = "key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;";
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =
    input.TrimEnd(';').Split(';').ToDictionary(item => item.Split('=')[0], item => item.Split('=')[1]);
```

Loop version:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string[] items = input.TrimEnd(';').Split(';');
foreach (string item in items)
{
    string[] keyValue = item.Split('=');
    dictionary.Add(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
}
```