# Convert a delimited string to a dictionary<string,uint> in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How do I convert the string to a `Dictionary<string, uint>`?

There are already answers to this & I tried this but it gives me error.

```
string abc = "key1=value1,key2=value2";
```

And below thing gives error:

```
var dict = text.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(part => part.Split('='))
           .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);
```

I'm not sure how to store the value as `uint` in dictionary. Any suggestions?

**Update**: and at later point I want to convert this `Dictionary<string, uint>` back to a comma-separated string (`key=value`). How do I do that reverse conversion using linq?

Comment: Go with @dasblinkenlights' solution - but here's a method to convert back to the string - `String.Join(",", dict.Select(kvp => String.Format("{0}={1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close - all you need is to parse `uint` for the value:

```
Dictionary<string,uint> dict = text.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Select(part => part.Split('='))
       .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => uint.Parse(split[1]));
```

Comment: Cool. And at later point I want to conver back this dictionary<string, uint> to comma separated string (key=value). How do I do that reverse conversion using linq?

Comment: @FreephonePanwal Going back is less of a LINQ - it's mostly `string.Join`: `string.Joun(",", dict.Select(p=>p.Key+"="+p.Value))`