# How to convert into a dictionary an array or list collection of strings being a set of key and value pairs delimited or separated by a char?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary, key-value

I have a string array and I am trying to process it.

`string [] datalist= new string[] {"A:1300", "D:1430", "D:343", "G:5340" };`

I want to separate each entry into a key and value (key is A,D,G and value is 1300, 1430, 343, 5340.

I will then be processing the values and finally converting back to a sorted array.

My solution involves converting the array into a List so I can query for individual items or groups but I still have to do lots of string manipulation to separate the key from the value.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>(datalist);
List<string> existingItems = items.FindAll(x => x.StartsWith("D:"));
```

I think there must be a better way - perhaps string array to dictionary and back again. What would be a better object to use so I can avoid using the colon in my searches. I understand that I will have to do it once to separate the strings into key and value. I will be doing different processing once I have the items and their values.

Comment: And a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` is not suitable for you? Or list of tuple, or custom class, or `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: A `KeyValuePair` would be ideal as @TheGeneral suggested.  look at my answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a delimited string to a dictionary<string,uint> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091071/convert-a-delimited-string-to-a-dictionarystring-uint-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You should elaborate on what "processing the items" means

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple items with the same key, a `Lookup` would make more sense. You can use `.ToLookup` for this:

```cs
var datalist = new string[] {"A:1300", "D:1430", "D:343", "G:5340" };

var items = datalist
    .Select(s => s.Split(':', 0))
    .ToLookup(s => s[0], s => s[1]);

var existingItems = items["D"];

var reassembledArray = datalist
    .SelectMany(key =>
        key.Select(val => key + ":" + val)
    ).ToArray
```

Comment: i think the usage of a `LookUp` is bit different than this. `LookUp()` can be used for 1 key many items. since here 1 key has only 1 item a `KeyValuePair` must work

Comment: We have here `D:1430` and `D:343` so not sure your point

Comment: yes, i noticed. since in the question it states it needs  a key value pair for each group the i think the `KeyValuePair` will suite.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var list = datalist.Select( item => new {
                                            Key= item.Substring(0,item.IndexOf(":")),
                                            Value= item.Substring(item.IndexOf(":")+1) 
                                           }).ToList();
```

you can use this way

```
var existingItems = list.Where(i=>i.Key=="D");
```

output (json format)

```
[
  {
    "Key": "D",
    "Value": "1430"
  },
  {
    "Key": "D",
    "Value": "343"
  }
]
```

or

```
var existingItems = list.Where(i=>i.Key=="D").Select(i=> i.Value).ToArray();
```

output

```
["1430","343"]
```