# Convert a delimited string to a List of KeyValuePair<string,string> in C#

Tags: c#, linq

My question is very similar to [Convert a delimted string to a dictionary<string,string> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141208/convert-a-delimted-string-to-a-dictionarystring-string-in-c-sharp), except instead of `Dictionary<String, String>`, I want `List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>` (in my case order of those key-value pairs is important)

So, to rephrase my problem:

I have a string in the following format `"key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3"`. I need to convert it to a `List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>` for the above mentioned key value pairs.

I can do this without using LINQ, but can this be done using LINQ? and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some tricky stuff with splitting your string. Basically, you need to split by your main delimiter (`';'`) so you end up with: `key1=value1`, `key2=value2`, `key3=value3`. Then, you split each of those by the secondary delimiter (`'='`). `Select` that into a new key value pair of strings. It should look similar to this:

```
var str = "key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3";

List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvp = str.Split(';')
                                            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>
                                                      (x.Split('=')[0], x.Split('=')[1]))
                                            .ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

As suggested in comment by [Joel Lucsy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645/joel-lucsy), you can alter the select to only split once:

```
.Select(x => { var p = s.Split('='); return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(p[0],p[1]); })
```

Comment: You could also only do the split once with .Select( x => { var p = s.Split('='); return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(p[0],p[1]); } )

Comment: @JoelLucsy Did not know about initialize that temp variable inside the select. That's pretty cool and avoids splitting twice. Great comment!

Answer (score 0):

Try to split by semicolon and then split every item by equal sign

```
"key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3"
.Split(';')
.Select(x=>{
   var items=x.Split('=');
   return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(items[0],items[1]);
   })
 .ToList()
```