# Convert query string to key-value pair in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If I have a string like so:

```
"Name=Irwin&Home=Caribbean&Preference=Coffee"
```

is there a method in C# that can convert that to a key-value pair similar to Request.QueryString?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624/how-to-parse-a-query-string-into-a-namevaluecollection-in-net

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can try using `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`.

```
var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(yourString);
```

Comment: No need to new up a NVC, as `ParseQueryString` returns that type already.

Comment: But afaik it's not part of the Client Profile, that might be an issue. (Posted before I spotted the ASP.NET tag).

Comment: When you create code example, please avoid "var" as it can make the reader confused of what type is returned. Please specify "string" if this is the case?

Answer (score 19):

And now, for the longest LINQ expression...

```
var dict = "Name=Irwin&Home=Caribbean&Preference=Coffee"
    .Split('&')
    .Select(p => p.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(p => p[0], p => p.Length > 1 ? Uri.UnescapeDataString(p[1]) : null);
```

But be aware that it will throw if there are multiple keys with the same name.

If you want to protected yourself from this add:

```
    .GroupBy(p => p[0]).Select(p => p.First())
```

just before the `.ToDictionary` (and after the `.Select`)

this will take the first `key=value` of the multiple ones. Change `.First()` to `.Last()` to take the last one.

Comment: +1 In my case, more helpful than the accepted answer as I'm looking for the case of parsing a style= string of key:value[;key:value]...

Comment: Actually, that’s not all that long of a LINQ expression :-p. Also, if this really was intending to parse a query-like string, where’re the calls to [`Uri.UnescapeDataString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @binki You are right (on the second one) :-) Added... On the lengthness, posterity will decide :-)

Comment: Almost—the key could be written in escaped from in a query string as well ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the ToDictionary() method:

```
var input = "Name=Irwin&Home=Caribbean&Preference=Coffee";
var items = input.Split(new[] { '&' });
var dict = items.Select(item => item.Split(new[] {'='})).ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1]);
```

Comment: This is the way to go if you don't want a dependency on System.Web, e.g. if you are developing for an API that inputs or outputs a querystring-like format.

Comment: Seems like a decent alternative for the `HttpUtility` approach for Xamarin and Maui.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for

[System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to split this string based on the ampersands and equals signs, then feed each one into a new KeyValuePair:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myValues = new Dictionary<string,string>();

string[] elements = myString.Split('=','&');

for(int i=0;i<elements.Length; i+=2)
{
   myValues.Add(elements[i], elements[i+1]);
}
```

This is simplistic and makes a lot of assumptions about the format of your string, but it works for your example.