# Binding querystring values to a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, query-string

I'm using Web API (part of ASP.NET MVC 5), and I'm trying to bind querystring values to a `Dictionary<int, bool>`.

My Web API method is simply:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/items")]
public IQueryable<Item> GetItems(Dictionary<int, bool> cf)
{
    // ...
}
```

If I try to invoke this URL:

```
/api/items?cf[1009]=true&cf[1011]=true&cf[1012]=false&cf[1015]=true
```

The parameter `cf` is always `null`.

How can I pass in a dictionary of values via the QueryString to a Web API method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want to pass a dictionary (basically key and value pair) using a query string parameter then you should use format like:
`&parameters[0].key=keyName&parameters[0].value=keyValue`

In my Action method signature, parameters is defined as:

```
Dictionary<string,string> parameters
```

Hope this helps.

I was able to figure this our myself after reading [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) from Scott Hanselman. So thanks to Scott!!

Thanks,
Nirav

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I was not in control of the URL so this didn't work for me (I couldn't append `.key`/`.value`) - I ended up just manually iterating through `Request.Form` and parsing the results by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way of doing this. On this case, "cf[1009]" is the name of the parameter, not "cf". You can write you own query string parser to achieve what you need. A better signature would be:

```
/api/items?cf=1009&cf=1011&cf=1015
```

And you bind it by using:

```
public IQueryable<Item> GetItems(List<int> cf)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't match the OP's requirements. There is more information needed about the `cf` entries: i.e. "true" or "false".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ModelBinder for your dictionary, as described on this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22708383

Comment: While this link may answer the question, [it is better](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.