# How to pass key values pairs to HttpGet in ASP.NET Core WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a WebApi and I need to take a key value pairs for my `GET` endpoint. I found some examples of using dictionary in `POST` method bus this seems not to work with `GET`

So far I tried this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] Dictionary<string, string> myVar)
{
}
```

I am using swagger to test the API and if I pass `{"key":"value"}` I am getting my dictionary with a single pair and value is the entire object I pass in. (`{[myVar, {"key":"value"}]}`)

What is the correct way to pass multiple key value pairs to the WebApi for `GET` method?

EDIT: The underlying issue was that I was using swagger (swashbuckle) to test my endpoint. And at the moment of this question it doesn't support dynamic query parameters [Issue on github](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/720). It should support it once OpenApi v3 support is added to swashbucle [Issue on github](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/671).

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/43594521/34092 help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to call the endpoint using the following structure and have the values automatically bound via Web API's built-in binder.

https://example.com/api/values?1=john&2=jane

1 and 2=keys for respective entries in dictionaries.
john and jane=values

Comment: I have tried it using Postman, but I get my dictionary corrucpted with `Key [string]:"myVar" Value [string]:null`. It seems that I am missing something

Comment: It looks like .NET Core model binder is different that .NET Framework version and it doens't like the previous syntax using the [].   I'll update the answer with what appears to work for .NET Core.