# Convert byte array into a Dictionary or NameValueCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, string, google-checkout

I have the following line in my code which clearly returns a byte array:

`byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadValues(uriString, data);`

When I do `myWebClient.Encoding.GetString(responseArray)` I get the following:

`_type=checkout-redirect&redirect-url=https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.google.com%2Fcheckout%2Fview%2Fbuy%3Fo%3Dshoppingcart%26shoppingcart%3D608260789399787`

So as you can see, this is a perfect candidate for converting to something that has a key and a value. So my question: is there any C# function to do that for me or do I have to parse the string myself and do it all manually?

Also, what about the redirect-url, I do not think I could redirect users to it the way it is, so I guess I have to decode it? Any suggestions on how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question about redirect -- maybe that would make more sense if it was a question all to itself and you explained more?

Comment: @Hogan: I mean, the redirect-url is encoded, right? If you grab it and try to go to it using your browser, it wouldn't work. So theoretically, doing that with code should not work as well, or am I mistaken here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said here:
[How to parse a query string into a NameValueCollection in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624/how-to-parse-a-query-string-into-a-namevaluecollection-in-net)

There's a built-in .NET utility for this: HttpUtility.ParseQueryString

Comment: Why would someone not use `Request.QueryString`?

Comment: See my comment on your answer ;)

Comment: Not sure what the webclient is... the browser?  It sounds like you are talking about something specific to the google product... but still, this is code running on the server.

Comment: @Hogan: No, the WebClient is a .NET class that allows you to do HTTP POST calls.

Comment: Not sure either although it sounds like a.... webClient class, long story short is that its a client, not a server (the name implies that)

Comment: @Polity: Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. It actually solved both problems posted in my question. +1 and thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

There already is a name value collection in `Request.QueryString`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx

Comment: Its about an outgoing request using the Webclient. not an incoming