# .NET Core API - parse array in query string for HTTP GET

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, http-get

I am having trouble with one of my HTTP GET controller methods in my .NET Core 2.1 backend.
The method should take an array of type `Tags` as input, to return some objects which are tagged with these tags.

As far as I know it is not possible to use `[FromBody]` attribute for HTTP GET, as this will always lead to an empty result.

Considering this stack [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992848/parse-and-modify-a-query-string-in-net-core) with the following closed github issue [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7712), it should now be possible to parse complex array types using the `FromQuery` attribute, am I right?

Comming back to my question, I want to ask what would be the right syntax so that an HTTP GET method can have an array of a complex type as input? This includes I don't know how the the URL must look like.

my controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<ComplexType[]> ComplexTypesByTags([FromQuery]Tags[] tags)
{
   // do some stuff with 'Tags[] tags' array
}
```

Tags model:

```
public partial class Tags
{
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

API endpoint is: `http://localhost:44381/api/v1/tags`

Comment: I can't help you without knowing what the URL looks like.

Comment: tags at end of URL is for matching the corresponding controller, 
I don't want to remove the tags parameter from my action. As I said above I need to know how a possible URL ending can look like for passing a complex type..

Comment: the url isn't containing tags at its end because that is the point I need to know how to implement