# Prevent URL encoding at QueryString.Add()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, odata

I am making a Restful api using OData, and for some reasons I want to force the expand filtering inside the middleware.

So if the clients sends in

> http://localhost:52973/odata/customers

The Middleware should automatically change it into

> http://localhost:52973/odata/customers?$expand=Contact,Address

In order to do this I've made a simple if statement inside my middleware

```
if (ctx.Request.Path.Value.Contains("customers") && !ctx.Request.QueryString.Value.Contains("?$expand"))
{
    string uri = @"?$expand=";
    ctx.Request.QueryString = ctx.Request.QueryString.Add(uri, "Contact,Address");
}
```

Unfortunately, it keeps generating the following: `{?%3F%5C$expand%5C%3D=Contact,Address}`

I've tried adding backslashes inside the uri string, but that didn't solve it.

Comment: That's just URL encoding. '%3F' is '?', '%5C' is '\' and '%3D' is '='

Comment: how do I remove it.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29993210/4033690

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that it is url-encoding ("escaping") the '$' character to make it safer, so I would not approach this problem from that angle. I would modify your consumers of this request to url-decode the request, which may be automatically done. See [QueryString.ToUriComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.querystring.touricomponent?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_QueryString_ToUriComponent), and also the QueryString.ToString() method too.