# Trying to figure out a good way to OrderBy on IQueryable using a string of a property name C# .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, iqueryable

I am passing in a query string that specifies a property to sort on but need to translate that to a property value in a model.

```cs
public class A
{
   public int Prop1 {get; set;}
   public int Prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

query string segment sort=Prop1

Server Side Code
query is a IQueryable

```cs
query.OrderBy(x => x.{properyName})
```

I have parsed the property name value from the query string but now I need to translate that to x.Prop1 in the orderby lambda not sure a great way without using reflection

Comment: If you're trying to extract parts of the uri https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992848/parse-and-modify-a-query-string-in-net-core

Comment: Why use reflection? just do a `switch (sort) { case "prop1": query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Prop1); break; }`

Comment: I can get the parts from the Uri. I like that thanks man