# Converting HttpRequest to HttpRequestData azure function

Tags: azure-functions, .net-5

I am moving some functions to .net 5 isolated process but I am not sure about how to extract data
using the new HttpRequestData in .net core I could do req.Query["blah"]

How do you do it in .net 5 with HttpRequestData?

**.net 3.1**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
        string fieldA = req.Query["fieldA"];
        string fieldB = req.Query["fieldB"];

        //etc...        
}
```

**.net 5**

```
 public  async Task<IActionResult>  Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext)
 {
        
        string fieldA = //????  req.Query["fieldA"];
        string fieldB = //???req.Query["fieldB"];

            //etc..             
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpRequestData.Url Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.http.httprequestdata.url?view=azure-dotnet) has [Uri.Query Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.query?view=net-5.0#System_Uri_Query).

You can use

```
var queryDictionary = 
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(
       HttpRequestData.Url.Query);
```

As suggested in [Parse and modify a query string in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992848/parse-and-modify-a-query-string-in-net-core)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, it seems a bit of a step back, surely there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: @developer9969, I don’t understand what is the step back? I’ve updated the answer to make it a bit clear. Have you found a better way since then?