# Are there any methods to help me manipulate the query string parameters?

Tags: c#, string, url, query-string

At the moment I'm using all sorts of if statements and substrings in order to manipulate the query string parameters and wanted to know if there was a more efficient way of doing it.

To be precise - I'm needing to add a query string parameter to the current url but if it already exists - I need to just amend it.

To clarify - I CAN achieve this using standard string manipulation methods, and I know how to retrieve the current url etc. I'm just wondering if these wheels are already in place and I'm re-inventing them.

Comment: Manipulate from which language? Javascript or C#?

Comment: Have a look at this link you might get the answer or alternate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624/how-to-parse-a-query-string-into-a-namevaluecollection-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
```

For more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the query string as a `Dictionary<string,string>` and use this to manipulate and then simply format the key value pairs as appropriate when outputting as a query string once more:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(string queryString)
{
    return queryString.TrimStart('?').Split('&').Select(qp => qp.Split(',')).ToDictionary(a => a[0], a=> a[1]);
}

public Dictionary<string, string> ToString(Dictionary<string, string> queryString)
{
    return '?' + string.Join('&', queryString.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + '=' + kvp.Value));
}
```