# how to convert string to string array?

Tags: c#, query-string

I have a object of type string,I want to convert it to String array

here the code is

```
 obj.QueryString =HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

 string[] arr =obj.QueryString;
```

QueryString is of type string.

Comment: Do you want to show us an example?

Comment: It's a very poorly formulated question. Based on the code and with no detailed explanation, I'm guessing you'll want to String.Split. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Comment: What should the array contain? One item containing the whole query string? The query string split by `&`s? Or split by `&`s and `=`s? Or something else?

Comment: Aren't query strings usually decomposed as Maps?

Comment: @sriram see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/68648/138071 and you can convert this to array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly access the each index within the string. For example

```
string value = "Dot Net Perls";
char first = value[0];
char second = value[1];
char last = value[value.Length - 1];

// Write chars.
Console.WriteLine("--- 'Dot Net Perls' ---");
Console.Write("First char: ");
Console.WriteLine(first);
Console.Write("Second char: ");
Console.WriteLine(second);
Console.Write("Last char: ");
Console.WriteLine(last);
```

Output

```
--- 'Dot Net Perls' ---
First char:  D
Second char: o
Last char:   s
```

Answer (score 2):

a string is nothing more then an array of chars, so if you want to split up the strings letters into a different string array seperatly you could do something like this:

```
string myString = "myString";
string[] myArray = new string[myString.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
{
        myArray[i] = myString[i].ToString();
}
```

or Char Array:

```
string theString = "myString";
char[] theStringAsArray = theString.ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert whatever character you want to split on instead of the "&" argument in the Split method call.

```
obj.QueryString =HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
string[] arr =obj.QueryString.Split(new char[] {'&'});
```

Comment: The  `Split` method takes a `char` as the delimiter argument you are passing a `string`.

Comment: It would be better to just change `"&"` to `'&'`... And split does not accept a string...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to convert to char[] array instead string[] array. to do this use `char[] arr = obj.QueryString.ToCharArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Here, this will make an array that may or may not fit your criteria.

```
var myArray = (from x in obj.QueryString select x.ToString()).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this compactly with Linq (similar to A.R.'s answer), but I can't speak to how efficient it is.

```
using System.Linq;
string input = "abcde";
var output = input.Select(char.ToString).ToArray();

> output
string[5] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" }
```