# How to correct parse query string in C# if value contains ampersand?

Tags: c#

I need parse query string: `?artist=singer1 & singer2&song=name song`

Static method `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` doesn't work the way I want if value contains ampersand like "singer1 & singer2".

For example:

```
string qs = "?artist=singer1 & singer2&song=name song"; 
NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(qs);
```

Result is:

> 1. artist = singer1
> 2. null = singer2
> 3. song = name song

I would like result

```
artist = singer 1 & singer2
song = name song
```

Any idea?

Comment: And what result did you expect?

Comment: HttpUtility.ParseQueryString work corectly, your query string is incorrect, each parament MUST have both name and value

Comment: Errr - what were you expecting? The posted results look right to me...

Comment: Actually, `&singer2&` should be parsed as `singer2=<empty>`, not the other way around.

Comment: `&` is a reserved symbol use another symbol to combine singer1 to singer2

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I suspect that it is and the OP wrote it down backwards.

Comment: what do you mean 'doesnt work correctly'? the query string has two parts e.g. 'artist=singer', your 'singer2' does not have the first part, that is why its `null`.

Comment: Those spaces don't look very good. Shouldn't they be encoded? From the RFC : "The space character is unsafe because significant spaces may disappear and insignificant spaces may be introduced when URLs are transcribed or typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs"

Comment: @cdhowie Actually, it seems HttpUtility parses it incorrect, it does indeed give it the name `null`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Hah, that's rather bizarre...

Comment: Closed as duplicate for standard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624/how-to-parse-a-query-string-into-a-namevaluecollection-in-net as this particular one really caused by invalid expectations/invalid string passed from client. There is nothing wrong with ParseQueryString.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The ampersand (`&`) in the middle of one of your values is throwing off the parser since it's a reserved symbol.  Replace it with its numeric code instead:

```
string qs = "?artist=singer1+%26+singer2&song=name song"; 
NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(qs);
```

Comment: Thanks, client application send me incorrect query string.

Comment: [How to build a query string for a URL in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c) is good place to copy code to build urls.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that `&` carries special meaning in a query string, namely to separate arguments.  The `&` in the middle of your perceived `artist` parameter is *actually* being parsed as an *argument separator*. You need to URL encode the `&` when constructing the URL.

For example, one correct query string would be:

```
?artist=singer1+%26+singer2&song=name+song
```

(Spaces can usually be encoded either as `+` or `%20`, but that's a topic for another discussion.)

You can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` when building the query string components to ensure that the result is correctly escaped.  For example, you could build the query string like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values["artist"] = "singer1 & singer2";
    values["song"] = "name song";

    Console.WriteLine(CreateQueryString(values));
}

static string CreateQueryString(NameValueCollection values)
{
    if (values == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }

    return string.Join(
        "&",
        values.AllKeys.Select(key => HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key) + "=" +
                                     HttpUtility.UrlEncode(values[key]))
                      .ToArray());
}
```

In other words, the issue is occuring *at the time you build the query string*, not when you are trying to parse it.  When parsing it you already have a semantically incorrect query string; there's nothing you can do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want artist = `singer1 & singer2` you need to escape or encode the `&` in your query string.

for example, if I ask Google about `fred & blotts`
the resulting query string contains `&q=fred+%26+blotts` rather than `&q=fred+&+blotts`

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-12