# Extracting digits from string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract some digits from a string: `foo=bar&hash=00000690821388874159\";\n`

I tried making a group for the digit, but it always return an empty string.

```
string matchString = Regex.Match(textBox1.Text, @"hash=(\d+)\\").Groups[1].Value;
```

I never use regex, so please tell me what I'm missing here.

Comment: It **works** as expected. `string matchString = Regex.Match(@"foo=bar&hash=00000690821388874159\"";\n", @"hash=(\d+)\\").Groups[1].Value;` returns `00000690821388874159`

Comment: @L.B. that's because you used the `@` which read the \ as a normal character and not an escape sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `\\` in your string, the `\` is in fact used to escape a quote so that's why the regex doesn't match. This works:

```
string matchString = Regex.Match(textBox1.Text, @"hash=(\d+)""").Groups[1].Value;
```

http://dotnetfiddle.net/2U0lkI

Comment: +1. Side note: original string looks like query string and there are much better way to parse it `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` (if reference is acceptable) See also [How to parse a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624/how-to-parse-a-query-string-into-a-namevaluecollection-in-net)