# Extracting data url using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, url

I have urls

```
domain.com
domain.com/
www.domain.com
http://www.domain.com
http://domain.com
domain.com/catalog/nextcatalog/
domain.com/catalog/nextcatalog/page.html
domain.com/page.html
domain.com/page.html?arg=123&arg2=abc
```

I want to get data like this

```
[0] = domain.com
[1] = catalog/nextcatalog/
[2] = page.html
[3] = arg=123&arg2=abc
```

I dont know how to get data from link like this

```
domain.com
```

In that case in **[0]** i have **http:**

It is possible to create universal regex that can skip for example catalog or page if its not in link?

I tried to create patern like this `^(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*?)(?=\/)(.*)(?=\/)(.*)$` but this dont work in all cases

Comment: And how looks pattern which you use now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use existing [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class which provides easy access to parts of uri. Some of urls in your sample list don't have scheme, so you just need to add it manually:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(url.StartsWith("http") ? url : "http://" + url);
```

Now you can use [`Uri.Host`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) to get host of uri. For you sample input hosts will be

```
"domain.com"
"domain.com"
"www.domain.com"
"www.domain.com"
"domain.com"
"domain.com"
"domain.com"
"domain.com"
"domain.com"
```

You can do simple string replace to get rid of `www` part:

```
uri.Host.Replace("www.", "")
```

Next goes query parameters. You can get them from [`Url.Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx). In your sample input only one url has query parameters. Returned value will be

```
?arg=123&arg2=abc
```

Again, it's easy to get rid of starting `?`:

```
uri.Query.TrimStart('?') // arg=123&arg2=abc
```

Uri also has [`Segments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx) collection which will contain array of segments. You can check if last segment contains `.` to get next result:

```
uri.Segments.Last().Contains('.') ? uri.Segments.Last() : ""
```

If this is true, then you will get `page.html` in last segment. Output:

```
""
""
""
""
""
""
"page.html"
"page.html"
"page.html"
```

You also can use simple `String.Join` to concatenate other segments into string. Or you can do string replace on [`Uri.LocalPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath.aspx):

```
uri.Segments.Last().Contains('.') ?
   uri.LocalPath.Replace(uri.Segments.Last(), "") : uri.LocalPath;
```

Output:

```
""
""
""
""
""
"/catalog/nextcatalog/"
"/catalog/nextcatalog/"
"/"
"/"
```

All you need to do is `TrimStart` to get rid of slash.

Comment: +1. Don't forget to use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to [parse query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624/how-to-parse-a-query-string-into-a-namevaluecollection-in-net)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov completely agree with you. That will be next step of parsing url :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Uri` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) to parse URLs as that class is designed to follow the relevant RFCs for parsing.  That class will let you access the Scheme, host, port, path, querystring, etc of the URL it parses.