# Send datas from PHP to vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net

So I would like to send more than 1 datas from PHP to vb.net how can I do that?

I tried for example this:

PHP:

```
name=test&password=123456&email=test@gmail.com
```

But how can I get this data in vb.net into strings?

```
Dim data = "name=test&password=123456&email=test@gmail.com"
Dim name = data("string")
```

??

Or how?

Comment: What do you mean by "Send"? How do you do that? Is the VB.NET code running inside an ASP.NET web page?

Comment: Do you mean [parsing query strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624/how-to-parse-a-query-string-into-a-namevaluecollection-in-net)? Like `name=test&password=123456` -> `collection(name=test,password=123456)`?

Comment: You can try to pass your data from php to vb.net, by calling system function here is some documentation: [PHP: system - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

Comment: well, I have a string "name=test&password=123456&email=test@gmail.com" and I wanna get the values in vb. For example: Dim name = string("name") -> and the value would be test

Comment: what kind of vb.net application

Comment: what kind of vb.net application?