# ASP.NET GET parameters with square brackets

Tags: asp.net, string, get

I don't know what they are called, that's why I can't find a solution.
I have a querystring looks like an array

`params[name]=john&params[age]=25&params[country]=ru`

Is there a way to parse these parameters as `string[]` or `Dictionary<string, string>`?

UPD:
On php this type of query string is being parsed automaticaly using

`$params = $_GET['params'];
$params['name']`

But I can't find an equivalent on C#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624/how-to-parse-a-query-string-into-a-namevaluecollection-in-net

Comment: I didn't find information about parsing with `[]`so that it can be accessable as `nvc["name"]`, not `nvc["params[name]"]`

Comment: @IrishChieftain that stackoverflow article is very different from what's asked here.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the ASP.NET MVC Framework, the default parameter binder that converts query string values into typed parameters can deal with it automatically in the following way:

**One-Dimensional Arrays**

```
// GetData?filters[0]=v1&filters[1]=v2&filters[3]=v3
public ActionResult GetData(IEnumerable<string> filters) 
{
    // todo
}
```

**Two-Dimensional Arrays**

```
// GetData?filters[0][field]=name&filters[0][type]=1&filters[0][value]=val
public ActionResult GetData(IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>> filters) 
{
    // todo
}
```

... and so on.

For more info and examples, check out [this blog post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-c-sharp-parse-query-string-get-parameter-arrays-square-bracket-notation-http/) that I wrote on this topic.